# Get next MYSQL Entry with stay my ordering

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

in a CRM a customer search for data and sort it and open one data like the data on position number 9 with id 12, now the customer and will save and get the next entry, how i will get now the first entry after mine here with example id 6?

in the past i fetched all and did a loop for search my entry and get the next but i think theres should be a better option, my way was kind of bad performance.

thanks

```
  SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE age > 18 ORDER BY age DESC
Example of DB
    |id|Name      |age|
    |9 |perso1    |66 |
    |10|rergfdgd  |55 |
    |11|gthfghfh  |44 |
    |9 |hghghgh   |33 |
    |1 |kgthht    |22 |
    |2 |ghjgj     |21 |
    |3 |fhgjg     |20 | 
    |4 |hjhjhjh   |19 |
    |12|ghgjgjg   |18 |
    |6 |tgjhgf    |17 |
    |7 |jhmgmhg   |16 |
    |8 |fghgjgjg  |15 |
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the position of the last row you found was 9, the a combination of `order` and `limit` in a select can fetch the right data...

```
SELECT * 
    FROM testdata 
    WHERE age > 18 
    ORDER BY age DESC
    LIMIT 9,1
```

Note that this effectively says - ignore the first 9 rows and fetch just 1 row.

See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/select/#limit for more details

Comment: seems interesting thanks the problem is thaht the data can be less or more, its  a crm so people can work on it but this can be interesting to reduce the data i had to loop if theres no any other solution for company case there are only 2 guys working on the same campain

Comment: maybe i should play with store the next and prev entrys direct in my react state when i open the data so its easy to goto next

Comment: Difficult is that if someone else is already working on the next entry.  Sounds like you need a queue and you just keep fetching the next entry.  New entries get added to the end of the queue.

Comment: if someone is working on next it will be shown or i will get next entrys, i also have to create somethings like this, we have a fast worker and a slow, the slow calls a guy and need ages to insert data, durring this the other have the data and also call the guy who is pissed of thahts hey called again, problems over problems haha

Answer (score 1):

If you want the query be fetched in order, a cursor would be the right solution: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree, pulling a complete result set and looping through them each time would work fine, but there are more elegant ways to handle this.

Here are my recommendations.

Option 1: 
Use a boolean field to flag whether or not a record has already been edited. In this example, the field `edited` would have a default of 0 (false). Once a record is edited, change the `edited` flag to 1 (true).

Your select query would then look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE age > 18 and edited = 0 ORDER BY age DESC limit 1
```

Then, in your php code, there is no need to loop through the results, the first record (and only record if you include the `LIMIT 1`) in your query would be the next record that hasn't yet been edited.

Option 2: add a `date_modified` field with a default of NULL. When a record is edited, save `now()` in the `date_modified` field.  Your query would then be:

```
SELECT * FROM testdata WHERE age > 18 and date_modified IS NOT NULL ORDER BY age DESC limit 1
```

Like in the first option, there is no need to loop through the results, the first record (and only record, if you include the `LIMIT 1`) in your query would be the next record that hasn't yet been edited.

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple users accessing the system at once? If that's the case, then this method will still work. Instead, as each user retrieves a record, flag the record as "retrieved" before serving to the screen. This will prevent the next user from getting the same record. Also, I'd wrap the query in `<cflock> </cflock>` to prevent two users from getting the same record at the same time